# leaflet markerclusterGroup layerGroup

Tags: leaflet

I want to add circle and marker (with same latlng), but want to treat it as a one element in cluster.
Is it possible to do it?

```
 L.layerGroup([L.marker(latnLng), L.circle(latnLng]);
```

Doesn't work.
It treats them as two elements.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible out of the box

Comment: Have you looked into using the [featureGroup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#featuregroup)?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't help.